# Balance the values using SQL in PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

My Postgresql table looks like,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
AS VALUES
    (1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A'),
    (2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A'),
    (3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (4, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B'),
    (5, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A'),
    (6, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A'),
    (7, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (9, 'Sub_C',  2, 'Group_B');
```

The power calculation works like this:

```
Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_A is (4 + 5 ) = 9
Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_A is ((-1) + 1 ) = 0
Total Power of Subgroup Sub_A in the grp Group_B is ((-1) + (-1) ) = -2
Total Power of Subgroup Sub_B in the grp Group_B is (6 + 2 ) = 8
So the power of Sub_A in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_A in the Group_B

So the power of Sub_B in the Group_A is not equal to power of Sub_B in the Group_B
```

I can query the database and fetch the data where for a same `subgroup` name total `power` is not equal across all the other `grp` names.

```
SELECT f.*
FROM  (
   SELECT subgroup
   FROM  (
      SELECT subgroup, grp, sum(power) AS total_power
      FROM   foo
      GROUP  BY subgroup, grp
      ) sub
   GROUP  BY 1
   HAVING min(total_power) <> max(total_power)
   ) sg
JOIN foo f USING (subgroup);
```

I also want to make the sum value identical. For a same `subgroup` name total `power` should be equal across all the other `grp` names.

We can fetch the records where sum is not equal from the above query. Then we can find the difference of `sum(power)` value and add this difference value into the `power` of any `subgroup` where `power` is smaller under that particular `grp`.

MySQL solution will be accepted as well.

The above query will return this data because for a same `subgroup` total `power` is not equal to across `grp` s,

```
(1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A')
(5, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A')
(3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B')
(7, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B')
(2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A')
(6, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A')
(4, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B')
(8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B')
```

Now, I want to modify the values of power to make the sum identical,

As an example, for Sub_A total power difference between Group_A and Group_B is (9-(-1-1)) = 11 , So we will add 11 into any of the Sub_A power value under Group_B, let's say we modify this record ,

`(3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B')` converted to `(3, 'Sub_A', 10, 'Group_B')`

The same thing we will do for others also, wherever there is an unbalanced.

Comment: can you give us desired result set

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you please check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below query will produce the desired result

```
  with foo(man_id, subgroup, power, grp) as (
    select * from
    (
    VALUES
    (1, 'Sub_A',  4, 'Group_A'),
    (2, 'Sub_B', -1, 'Group_A'),
    (3, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (4, 'Sub_B',  6, 'Group_B'),
    (5, 'Sub_A',  5, 'Group_A'),
    (6, 'Sub_B',  1, 'Group_A'),
    (7, 'Sub_A', -1, 'Group_B'),
    (8, 'Sub_B',  2, 'Group_B'),
    (9, 'Sub_C',  2, 'Group_B')
    ) as x(man_id, subgroup, power, grp)
), sub_per_group as (
  select
    subgroup,
    grp,
    sum(power) tot_per_grp
  from foo
  group by subgroup,grp
), sub_calc as (
select
  subgroup,
  max(tot_per_grp) as max,
  json_agg(
    json_build_object(
        'grp',grp,
        'tot_per_grp',tot_per_grp
    )
  ) as grps_tot
from sub_per_group
group by subgroup
having count(distinct tot_per_grp)!=1
)
select f.man_id,f.subgroup,
  case
      when rn=1 then
      (
        power+
        (
         coalesce(max,0)-
         coalesce((
           select (v->>'tot_per_grp')::int
            from
          json_array_elements(grps_tot) as v where (v->>'grp')::text =f.grp),0)
        )
      )
    else
     power
  end,
  f.grp
from sub_calc sc
right join (
  select
    row_number() over(partition by subgroup,grp) as rn,
    foo.*
  from foo
) f on f.subgroup=sc.subgroup and f.rn=1
order by subgroup,grp
```

Comment: Brilliant answer.